# Angular 2 - if query string present, load another stylesheet

Tags: angular, widget, stylesheet

I have an Angular 2 app and want to turn one of my components into an iframe widget when the query string `widget=true` is present.  When this string is present I want to load an additional stylesheet into the component to change the widget view a little bit.  Is this possible?  How would I do this?

*Just to clarify:*

I have a component that I use as a regular page but want to be able to have it as an iframe widget too. When the query string `widget=true` is present I will know that the page is in an iframe. In this case I want to load an additional stylesheet to the component

Comment: didn't get what you want. You want to turn a component into iframe or you want to load another style?

Comment: I have a component that I use as a regular page but want to be able to have it as an iframe widget too.  When the query string `widget=true` is present I will know that the page is in an iframe.  In this case I want to load an additional stylesheet to the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are several ways.

First, obvious and dirty, is including styles as `<style>` tag with `*ngIf` checking for this parameter in the URL.

Second, what I find better, is [setting the style into styleUrls component meta property](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#loading-styles):

```
let styleUrls = [];

if (window.location.href.contains('widget=true')) {
  styleUrls.push('/path/to/style');
}

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Tour of Heroes</h1>
    <hero-app-main [hero]=hero></hero-app-main>`,
  stylesUrls: 
})
export class HeroAppComponent {
/* . . . */
}
```

Comment: I didnt have any luck with *ngIf on the `<style>` tag but your second way worked great